# Why 'declare' is not working for 'extends' in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm examining Typescript right now, and stumbled upon a strange thing. I'm using 'typescript@1.5.0-alpha' installed via `npm` by default. If I have a code that `declare`'s a var and then uses it for assignment, all works fine.

**.ts**

```
declare var a;
var b = a;
```

**.js**

```
var b = a;
```

But if I declare a variable and then try to extend a class from it (assuming that variable is a valid typescript class identifier) typescript fails with strange error that "name" is not found:

**.ts**

```
declare var a;
class b extends a {}
```

**error**

```
test.ts(2,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'a'.
```

Any hints why this happens and what does TypeScript refers as "name"? Definitely it's not an "identifier", since identifier seems to be perfectly detected according to first version.

Comment: Why would you extend a class from a variable?

Comment: @Jimmy T. Reasonable question, seems that's a problem origin. But how can i instruct the Typescript that identifier "a" actually refers class, and typescript just needs to generate extend code assuming it's here (third-party minified lib)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..how can i instruct the `TypeScript` that identifier "a" actually refers class, and typescript just needs to generate extend code assuming it's here. defined in third-party minified lib. Is it any way to forward-declare it without describing it's inner structure? it's prototype is `node.js` `event.EventEmitter`

I **don't know** how to hack newest `TypeScript` compiler into doing what you want and from your problem description I actually didn't understand what you want...

...but I've stumbled across the need to declare types in 3rd party libraries and especially the `event.EventEmitter` variable types. I've worked around this need by declaring `interface` which copy/paste describes the important members of the inner structure.

It's marked with `TODO` as I could not find better solution at that time, but it may work as **workaround** in your case as well

**interfaces.d.ts**

```ts
/// <reference path="../../vendor/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts"/>

interface IChildProcess /* TODO: should be "extends child_process.ChildProcess" */ {
  stdin: NodeJS.WritableStream;
  stdout: NodeJS.ReadableStream;
  stderr: NodeJS.ReadableStream;
  pid: number;
  on(event: string, listener: Function): NodeJS.EventEmitter;
}
```

**some.ts**

```
var process: IChildProcess;

process = child_process.spawn("cmd.exe", args, {
  cwd: options.cwd || process.cwd(),
  stdio: options.stdio || 'inherit',
  env: process.env,
  detached: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to extend a class and **not** an object instance.

```
class A
{
  // stuff
}

class B extends A
{
  // stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's like this, but 'A' is defined in third-party minified lib. Is it any way to forward-declare it without describing it's inner structure?

Comment: So why exactly would you like to extend it? You don't even know it's prototype.

Comment: I know it's prototype because it's `node.js` `event.EventEmitter` :(. And it works perfectly if code is crafted by hand. Now I want it to be crafted by TypeScript, but this strange problem arise.